# PetaPoco request for int[] type not working

Tags: sql, petapoco, management-studio-express

Hello I am trying to make a fetch to Microsoft SQL Server Management studio where in one of my columns there is an array of ints that I want to retrieve based on another column value.

I am making the query like this:

```
int[] appsId = db.Fetch<int[]>($"SELECT Apps FROM [dbo].[Group] WHERE Name = @0", user.Groups[0]).FirstOrDefault();
```

The table has the following (shortened) info:

```
Name    Apps
123     [356, 1589]
```

Using this I get the exception: 'Input string was not in a correct format'.

Any ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably need to unpack that array in the query:

```
SELECT Value 
FROM [dbo].[Group] 
CROSS APPLY 
( 
   SELECT CAST(VALUE AS INT) Value 
   FROM OPENJSON(APPS) 
) v
WHERE Name = @0
```

Comment: PetaPoco is a wrapper for ado.net. I'm not up-to-date with the latest SQL Server types, but if SQL Server has an array type then support for it would need to be added to PP in order for OP's code to work. Until then, this is the correct workaround. OP, note that you would need to alter the fetch to be `Fetch<int>` and create the array yourself

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the following:

```
Entities.Database.Group dbScope = db.Fetch<Entities.Database.Group>($"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Group] WHERE Name = @0", user.Groups[0]).FirstOrDefault();
```

Since Group is the class that defines the Object you can then map the field that you need, in this case Apps.

Thanks everyone!